# Spring Batch - Bean Inheritance with JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm facing a problem with Spring Batch, which is normally pretty simple.

I have multiple steps, chunk processing oriented. For every steps, I want to use the same ItemReader.

```
<bean id="myItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
          scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql"
                  value="select * from ...."/>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="MyRowMapper" />
        </property>
</bean>
```

And here is my step declaration :

```
<step id="mySpecificStep">
    <tasklet>
         <chunk reader="mySpecificItemReader"
                       writer="myItemWriter"
                       commit-interval="${commit-interval}"
                       skip-policy="skipPolicy">
         </chunk>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

My request have some parameters, which I want to replace with a PreparedStatementSetter.

So my intention was to create multiples beans (for every steps), in order to call a specific PreparedStatement, for each bean.

```
<bean id="mySpecificItemReader" parent="myItemReader" >
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter" ref="mySpecificStatement"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mySpecificStatement" class="PreparedStatementSpecificProduct">
        <property name="product" value="XXX" />
</bean>
```

I have the following error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'preparedStatementSetter' of bean class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]: Bean property 'preparedStatementSetter' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

What am I doing wrong ? Let me know if you need more details.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct so I have deleted my answer. Let me relook at your set up.

Comment: Which version of Batch you looking at ? The version that I am looking at has only getter present for `sql` property.

Comment: I'm currently on 3.0.6.RELEASE. Sadly, I cannot upgrade it...

Comment: Mark the parent as `abstract`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally made it work ! Thanks to @M. Deinum, I used abstract on my declaration. Here is how I did it :

```
<bean id="myItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
          scope="step" abstact="true">
```

```
<bean id="mySpecificItemReader" parent="myItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="preparedStatementSetter">
              <bean id="mySpecificStatement" class="PreparedStatementSpecificProduct">
                  <property name="product" value="XXX" />
              </bean>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Thank you everyone for your help !